# Angular 10 adding numbers

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular10

```
loadingPercent: number = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    window.setInterval(function() {
      console.log(loadingPercent + 10);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

I am trying to simply add 10 every second but I get the answer NaN. I am using typescript in Angular 10. Why is simple addition so difficult?

Comment: yes. it still says NaN.

Comment: Just for clarification, this isn't an Angular 10 issue, this is a javascript scope issue. [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is inside `setInterval` function? You are not accessing the class scope.

This could be solved in three ways.

**Option 1:**

Use `arrow function` for `setInterval` that will explicily binds the scope inside `setInterval` to your class scope.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.increment();
  }, 1000);
}

increment() {
  this.loadingPercent = this.loadingPercent + 10;
  console.log(this.loadingPercent);
}
```

Working [Fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ulm8ze)

If you are not using arrow function, you need to bind scope manually.

**Option 2**

```
 loadingPercent = 0;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        that.increment();
    }, 1000);
  }

increment() {
    this.loadingPercent = this.loadingPercent + 10;
    console.log(this.loadingPercent);
}
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6b14xod/).

**Option 3**

```
  loadingPercent = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
      setInterval(this.increment.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  increment() {
      this.loadingPercent = this.loadingPercent + 10;
      console.log(this.loadingPercent);
  }
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6b14xod/1/).

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Can you give me a link to help me explain this?